# Use GeoJson data with Leaflet.PixiOverlay

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, geojson, react-leaflet

I am using Leaflet.PixiOverlay([this package](https://github.com/manubb/Leaflet.PixiOverlay)) in my App in order to render a big number of data(suck as markers, shapes, geoJson data, etc) without performance issues.

But the documentation of this package does not specify how to use data with GeoJson format to draw on leaflet map.

Does anybody know how to do that ?

Or is there a better way to have a good performance even with big amounts of data on leaflet maps ?

GeoJson Data Sample:

```
"jsonData": [
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]},
      "properties": {"prop0": "value0"}
      },
    { "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [102.0, 0.0], [103.0, 1.0], [104.0, 0.0], [105.0, 1.0]
          ]
        },
      "properties": {
        "prop0": "value0",
        "prop1": 0.0
        }
      }]
```